# unwanted SHOW COLUMNS queries in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp-1.3

This question my have asked before but i could not find it.

[image]

as you can see in above image there are few `SHOW COLUMNS` queries are firing which are generated by default by `cakephp`.

so is there a way to remove it or is it necessary for `cakephp.`?

**OR**

cakephp just use this when `debug` set to `2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing is CakePHP 'inspecting' the structure ("schema") of your database tables. CakePHP uses this information to *"know"* what field is present in each table and what *kind of field* it is, so that it can, for example, automatically generate the right type of input field with the `FormHelper`

Normally, those information will be cached, so that those queries only have to be executed once.

However, *because you enabled 'debug' mode, CakePHP will retrieve this information more often to discover changes made in the database structure during development.*

In debug-mode, the cache will be invalidated after 10 seconds, causing these queries to show up. (An important reason to *not* enable debug on a live website, as this will clearly affect performance)

Hope this explains the queries